# PHP: Postgres Array and pg_insert

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I know I can insert an array into a Postgres database with `pg_query`.

```
INSERT into table (field) VALUES ('{{element, element},{}}')
```

But how about using `pg_insert`?

```
$array["field"] = "{{element, element},{}}";
$result = pg_insert($con, "table", $array);
```

Will the string `{{element, element},{}}` be actually inserted into `field` as a **2D** Postgres array?

*I've always wanted to test that out but currently I don't have any PostgreSQL DB to test with..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran your specific example.

(1) in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE atable (afield text[][]);
```

(2) in PHP:

```
$array["afield"] = "{{'element', 'element'},{}}";
$result = pg_insert($this->conn, "atable", $array);
```

And I got the following error:

```
Notice: pg_insert(): Unknown or system data type '_text' for 'afield' in ...
```

I tried playing around with the array value: make it 2x2 array, one-dimensional, etc., etc. - the same result.  I even changed the table to have the field as one-dimensional array: `text[]` and changed the code accordingly - and I still get the same result.

I started digging further and found the following on [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-insert.php) for `pg_insert`:

> This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its
>   name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a
>   future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.

Basically, it's pretty buggy and shouldn't be used.  Interestingly, using

```
pg_query("INSERT INTO...")
```

works just fine.  Hopefully, this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As many dimensions as you like, but two is fine.

```
=> CREATE SCHEMA ztest;
CREATE SCHEMA
=> CREATE TABLE tt (a int[3][3]);
CREATE TABLE
=> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[4,5,6], ARRAY[7,8,9]]), (ARRAY[ARRAY[11,12,13],ARRAY[14,15,16],ARRAY[17,18,19]]);
INSERT 0 2
=> SELECT * FROM tt;
                 a
------------------------------------
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
 {{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{17,18,19}}
(2 rows)

=> INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('{{21,22,23},{24,25,26},{27,28,29}}');
INSERT 0 1
=> SELECT * FROM tt;
                 a
------------------------------------
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
 {{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{17,18,19}}
 {{21,22,23},{24,25,26},{27,28,29}}
(3 rows)

=> SELECT a[2][3] FROM tt;
 a
----
  6
 16
 26
(3 rows)
```